# Automatically picking up js errors in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Using VS Code and I keep hitting little snags in my JS workflow, example below:

In the following code theres an teeny error (highlighted).

```
module.exports = {
elems: {
    accordions: document.querySelectorAll('ul.m_accordion')
},
init: function() {
    this.render();
}, 
render: function() {
    if (!this.moduleValid()) {
        return;
    }
    this.attachListeners(this.elems.accordions);
}, 
moduleValid: function() {
    return this.elems.**accordion**.length > 0;
}, 
attachListeners: function (accordions) {
    for(var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++){
        console.log(this);
    }
}
}
```

Renamed a variable, missed one, webpacked up and (understandably) broke in browser, little debugging and its all working. Larger files though it becomes a bit of a pain. However it'd be great if those errors were picked up and shown in VSCode.

For referance and to show you what I see heres a small screenshot of the same js code, in the vs code with the error visible, but 'invisible'

[image]
(Ignore my little scribble - purely to draw the eye to my woe)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ESLint extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

ESLint is meant to check your javascript for syntactical errors, also forces you to write your script in a specific manner which you can configure. E.g. you can force every developer to avoid writing JSON in single line etc.

You can configure the rules using `.eslintrc` file in root of your application. Check https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring. Following is an example of a `.eslintrc` file

OR

If you want absolute type checking and compilation benefits like C# or JAVA then use `TypeScript`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a go.